# Quadrilateral angles when inscribed inside square

Tags: geometry

"If we can draw a quadrilateral inscribed in a circle, its opposite sides must sum to 180∘."

Why is this?

Comment: 1) What have you attempted so far? (For example, have you drawn a diagram? What facts about polygons seem relevant?) 2) I don't understand what you mean by "its opposite sides must sum to $180^\circ$." Do you mean "opposite angles"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the cylic quadralateral I have drawn here:
[image]

It is using making use of the theorem that the angle subtended at the center is twice that subtended at the circumference.

The total angle at the center is therefore $2x+2y=360^0$ which implies that $x+y=180^0$

Comment: The theorem is more commonly known as the [Inscribed Angle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle).

Comment: @Semiclassical - thanks for clarifying that - it's been a very long time since I was last at high school so I couldn't quite remember the correct name for this theorem :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that a quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle, and that there is a point $E$ on a half line $DC$ outside of the circle.

By [the inscribed angle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), we have
$$\angle{DBC}=\angle{DAC},\angle{BAC}=\angle{BDC}.$$
Also, considering $\triangle{BCD}$, we have
$$\angle{BCE}=\angle{DBC}+\angle{BDC}.$$
Hence, 
$$\begin{align}\angle{BCD}+\angle{BAD}&=(180^\circ -\angle{BCE})+(\angle{BAC}+\angle{DAC})\\&=180^\circ-\angle{BCE}+(\angle{BDC}+\angle{DBC})\\&=180^\circ.\end{align}$$